# Regarding the deallocation of memory resources of a thread

Tags: multithreading

I was going through the man pages of pthread_join and its mentioned the following

"When  a joinable  thread  terminates,  its  memory  resources  (thread
       descriptor and stack) are not deallocated until another thread performs
       pthread_join on it. Therefore, pthread_join must  be  called  once  for
       each joinable thread created to avoid memory leaks."

The reason has for doing this has been mentioned as to avoid memory leaks. But, I am not sure why in the first place the resources for a particular thread need to be still kept upon its termination.

Jayaraj

Answer (score 1):

The thread descriptor is kept around so the thread procedure *return value* could be retrieved through the second parameter of `pthread_join(2)`. This is the same idea as with zombie processes.

Keeping the stack of terminated thread was probably a requirement of the particular thread library implementation at the time the API was formalized.